# PHP rake migrations equivalent for MongoDB

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am trying to tackle the issue of schema migrations in non-relational databases like MongoDB. If I rename or move a field within a document or even between collections, this can be handled well in rails by migrating the old data to the new location with rake tasks or migrations. Is there anything equivalent for PHP? I am aware of [ruckusing](https://github.com/ruckus/ruckusing-migrations) but I'm looking for something I could potentially use with MongoDB as well.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is a Framework on top of Ruby, so if you are searching the same kind of things in PHP you have ta have a look on PHP Frameworks like: [Flow3](http://flow.typo3.org/), [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Console-Applications/Schema-management-and-migrations.html), [Lithium](https://github.com/nashape/li3_ruckusing_migrations), [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) etc.

Some of them coming with Migration Helpers some dont.

Answer (score 1):

There is standalone library for PHP - https://github.com/sokil/php-mongo-migrator, specially for migrating mongodb schemas with CLI like yii's mirgations or other relational db migrating library http://phinx.org/

Comment: awesome - was looking for exactly this